# Textarea and div padding differences in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, gecko

I made a fiddle here.  http://jsfiddle.net/pmVeR/

The `textarea` and `div` render identically in both Safari and Chrome. But in Firefox, there is an extra `2px` padding on the right of the `textarea`, which affects the word wrapping.

What's also mysterious is that without `white-space: pre-wrap;` this extra padding seems to vary depending on the width of the element.

I can fix this by detecting FireFox and adding `padding-right:2px` to my `div`, but I would like to know if this can be fixed without a browser hack?

**CSS**

```
div, textarea {
    font-family: Courier;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    resize: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 282px;
    height: 80px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt...</textarea>
<div contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt...</div>
```

**EDIT**

The example I provided above is fixed width so you'd be able to see the problem but I need it to work for expanding widths too like this.
http://jsfiddle.net/pmVeR/6/

Comment: Works fine for me - both Chrome (26.0.1410.64) and Firefox (20.0.1) show both elements as the same width with text wrapping at the same characters.

Comment: same for me. A possible fix may be to specifically add padding. 'padding:4px;' for example.

Comment: @lukeocom - If you play around with the `width` you should be able to get the problem to show up, I can see it by setting `width: 275px;` in FireFox.

Comment: Works in FF 18 as well

Comment: which version of Firefox you are using?

Comment: indeed not working in my firefox

Comment: Firefox 20.0 on Mac OS X 10.8.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the described behaviour on `Firefox 20.0.1` using this <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pmVeR/4/)</kbd>.

I have had a bit of a look around for you, it seems that Firefox has had quite [some issues](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=157846) with [paddings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374537/how-to-force-firefox-to-render-textarea-padding-the-same-as-in-a-div) in [combination with textareas](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=84146) in the past, so I'm thinking you might not be able to get rid of it.

I'm not sure if you would class vendor specific prefixes as a browser hack, but I've got one for you.

You can add [`-moz-padding-start: 2px;`](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=84146) and [`-moz-padding-end: 2px;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-padding-end?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F-moz-padding-end) to your CSS rule, that will fix your wrapping issue: <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pmVeR/10/)</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks!  This was the prefix I was looking for but you only want to apply it to the div.  http://jsfiddle.net/pmVeR/7/  Also, whatever the padding is for the div/textarea you need to add 2px to -moz-padding-end.  In my example I changed the padding to 4px so -moz-padding-end is 6px.  Also in your fiddle you removed "white-space: pre-wrap;" but this needs to stay.

Comment: I have updated the answer, there was some more padding going on. I don't think `white-space: pre-wrap;` makes a difference for the behaviour, but I have added it again anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can use reset css for that too.